# E-mail automático pegando dados do banco de dados Oracle

Tags: java-ee

Tenho que fazer um projeto Java que faz envio de e-mail automático pegando dados como nome, CNPJ, etc. no banco de dados Oracle todos os dias as 10:00 am. Como criar isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem muitas formas de fazer isso, muitas mesmo.

Uma que considero bastante usual no mercado é usar o [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), um agendador de tarefas que suporta ambientes distribuídos (*cluster*) e que pode ser executado de forma integrada com o Spring Framework.

Nesse caso, basta criar uma [tarefa que dispare no horário desejado](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) usando o mesmo padrão do comando `cron` do Unix. Exemplo:

```
0 0 10 ? * *
```

A expressão acima define a execução diária para as 10 da manhã, horário exato, sem segundos ou minutos.

Usar o framework Spring pode ajudar nas demais tarefas, como configuração e envio de e-mail, conexão com o banco de dados, injeção de dependência dos componentes, etc.

Para mais detalhes de como configurar o Quartz com o Spring, consulta a [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html). Veja também tutoriais e exemplos [aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/agendando-tarefas-com-spring-e-quartz-revista-easy-java-magazine-25/26774) e [aqui](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/).

Dependendo do volume de e-mails, você pode integrar também o Spring Batch para envio de e-mails em certos intervalos. Então, neste cenário, a tarefa do Quartz dispararia a tarega do Spring Batch para envio de e-mails.

Comment: Brother voce teria algum projeto de exemplo para que eu pudesse começar a entender melhor esse lance? obrigado.

Comment: @WesleyCosta Os projetos que tenho são confidenciais, mas se seguir os tutoriais e exemplos que passei você tem o que é necessário para configurar o Spring com o Quartz. Na parte de acessar o banco de dados, pode usar [este outro exemplo com Spring JdbcTemplate](http://www.journaldev.com/2593/spring-jdbc-and-jdbctemplate-crud-with-datasource-example-tutorial). Para enviar e-mail veja [este](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/27/send-email-with-spring-javamailsenderimpl-example/) e [este outro](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/sending-e-mail-with-spring-mvc) link.

Comment: consegui fazer uma classe que envia e-mail no tempo que eu determinei, e também consegui criar uma classe que conecta no banco e me traz as informações que eu preciso, agora como faço pra os dois estejam em sintonia para que possa haver o preenchimento do corpo do email com os dados do cliente devedor?? se puder me ajudar amigo @utuluiz

Comment: @WesleyCosta Aí entra um problema simplesmente de orientação a objetos. Você ainda não conhece os conceitos de criar uma classe, um método, depois importar isso em outra classe? Seria melhor você estudar a linguagem Java um pouco. Infelizmente estou sem tempo para te dar uma solução mais mastigada.

Comment: blz, amigo acho que esse realmente e meu problema rsrsrs.. bom mais vou vendo oque eu posso fazer aqui... valeu

Answer (score 0):

Vai precisar de varias coisas em separado, primeira delas e um crontab sendo executado todos os dias as 10:00AM, segundo e um servidor SMTP configurado corretamente, somente após isso deve criar uma classe de acesso ao banco e disparo de e-mail.

Comment: não querendo ser chato, mais como seria isso?